# What's the return type of ffi when using a constructor function from c++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, ffi, node-ffi

Recently, I'm working on using c++ functions in JavaScript and I've chosen the ffi addon of nodejs. But I don't know how to write the return type of a c++ class constructor in JS.

My c++ code looks like this

```
//definition of a class
class Rectangle {
  private:
    int width, height;

  public:
    Rectangle (int,int);
    int area ();
    int perimeter ();
};

//definition of member functions
Rectangle::Rectangle (int a, int b) {
      width = a;
      height = b;
}

int Rectangle::area() {
    return width * height;
}

int Rectangle::perimeter() {
    return 2 * width + 2 * height;
}
```

And my js code looks like this

```
//'use strict';

var ref = require('ref');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');

//define types
var RectangleType = Struct({
  'x': 'int',
  'y': 'int'
});

var RectanglePtrType = ref.refType(RectangleType);
var hw = ffi.Library('../build/libnotemplateLib', {
       Rectangle:[/*what should I write here*/, ['int','int']]
         });

console.log(hw.Rectangle(3,4));
```

I've tried to use the structure "RectangleType" and the pointer "RectanglePtrType", but both of them cause a type error. All the results that I found in google are about LuaJIT but not nodejs.

If there is no return type that we can use in Js for a c++ constructor, is it possible for me to create a Rectangle object in JS?

Comment: "write the return type of a c++ class constructor" There is no such thing as the return value of a constructor.

Comment: I saw my professor did it. I remember he firstly `new` a RectangleType structure as an container and then use something like `ref()` to pass the container's address to the constructor. Finally, when the constructor is called, it changes the value of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I‘ve found an solution today.

We can write our Js code in this way

```
var hw = ffi.Library('../build/libnotemplateLib', {
       Rectangle:[RectanglePtrType, [RectanglePtrType，'int','int']]
         });

//usage of the constructor
var d = new RectangleType();
hw.Rectangle(d.ref(), 2, 9);
console.log(d);
/* out put is a javascript object
  { x: 2,
    y: 9,
  'ref.buffer': <Buffer@0x20397d8 02 00 00 00 09 00 00 00> }*/
console.log('C++ built rectangle area: ', hw.area(d.ref()));
//output is 18
```

If anyone has a similar problem as I do and want to figure out how exactly I solve it, you are welcome to visit [github.com/shenlin192/Projet-de-R-D](http://github.com/shenlin192/Projet-de-R-D)